# OWASP zap python api authentication

Tags: python, authentication, owasp, zap

I'd like to start off by saying that I love this tool and the API is written in a very easy to follow way if you are familiar with Zap. The only troubles I've had is that I can't find much documentation on the python API, so I've gone off of the source code and verifying how it works against the app. I've been able to pull of scans and set contexts, but I can't seem to be able to correctly call anything from the authentication module. One of my problems, I believe, is that I'm not entirely sure the exact variables to use or their respective formats when calling the functions. below is some example code that I've scrapped together. Every use of the authentication functions below fail me. Even if someone were to look at this and tell me where to go or look to solve this problem myself, I would be very grateful.

```
from zapv2 import ZAPv2

context = 'new_attack'

authmethodname = 'formBasedAuthentication'

authmethodconfigparams = "".join('loginUrl=someloginpage' 'loginRequestData=username%3D%7B%25user1%25%7D%26' 'password%3D%7B%25password%25%7D')

target = 'some target but I cant put more than 2 links in this question'

apikey = 'password'

zap = ZAPv2(apikey=apikey)

print zap.context.new_context('new_attack')

print zap.context.include_in_context(context, 'https://192.168.0.1.*')

print zap.context.context(context)

#anything below here gives me 'Missing Params' an error from zap
print zap.authentication.set_logged_in_indicator(context, loggedinindicatorregex='Logged in')

print zap.authentication.set_logged_out_indicator(context, 'Sorry, the username or password you entered is incorrect')


print zap.authentication.set_authentication_method(context, authmethodname, authmethodconfigparams)
```

Comment: Also thanks for the edit suggestion. My first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

A Dev member on the project was able to answer my question so I thought I would put it here as well. Essentially the authentication functions take the contextid and userid as parameters and I was passing the context name and user name. There are a few other mistakes that I interpreted from the source code as well. Hopefully this helps someone else who's starting out with the API as well, since there is not a lot of documentation.
from github page zaproxy; username thc202 - "

```
from zapv2 import ZAPv2
context = 'new_attack'
authmethodname = 'formBasedAuthentication'
authmethodconfigparams = "".join('loginUrl=https://192.168.0.1/dologin.html' '&loginRequestData=username%3D%7B%25username%25%7D%26' 'password%3D%7B%25password%25%7D')
target = 'https://192.168.0.1'
apikey = 'password'
zap = ZAPv2(proxies={'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8119', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8119'}, apikey=apikey)

contextid = zap.context.new_context(context)
print contextid
print zap.context.include_in_context(context, 'https://192.168.0.1.*')

print zap.context.context(context)

print zap.authentication.set_authentication_method(contextid, authmethodname, authmethodconfigparams)
# The indicators should be set after setting the authentication method.
print zap.authentication.set_logged_in_indicator(contextid, loggedinindicatorregex='Logged in')
print zap.authentication.set_logged_out_indicator(contextid, 'Sorry, the username or password you entered is incorrect')

userid = zap.users.new_user(contextid, 'User 1')
print userid
print zap.users.set_authentication_credentials(contextid, userid, 'username=MyUserName&password=MySecretPassword')
print zap.users.set_user_enabled(contextid, userid, True)

print zap.spider.scan_as_user(contextid, userid, target)
```

"